# Can't solve grid problems

Tags: css, grid-layout

I needed to develop my own grid layout. I put my code here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fznyw

Problem is - grid should be 12 columns. Widths are in percents. But I can't get my last element to stay in a row. What did I do wrong?

I tried using `margin-left:-30px` on `.container`, but it didn't helped. Only solution was, to make a class `.first-in-row` with `margin-left:0`, but, since those blocks will be reordered, I can't use this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed percentages a bit. I am not sure if there is better way of sorting those grids but I managed to find percentages for some of them, you could use this and finish all 12.

[preview - updated](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/moaqk)

Comment: I got this numbers from SASS, so it should be accurate. The problem is, I have 12 different sizes here and when I change them all, they won't stay equal while placed one over another.

Comment: I updated codepen, this is best I could do, I am not sure why you got those percentages. You could finish and find all 12 of them doing the same way I did, if nothing else helps.